# Binary Conversion in Java

Tags: java, object-oriented, converting, reinventing-the-wheel

Before implementing a GUI I tried performing it at CLI first and I also tried to implement it by using calling methods to another `class`.

`BinaryConversion` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import static java.lang.System.in;
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class BinaryConversion{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        try (Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            System.out.print("Enter given: ");
                int givenNum = in.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Binary: " + convert.getBinary(givenNum));
            System.out.println("Octal:  " + convert.getOctal(givenNum));
            System.out.println("Hex:    " + convert.getHex(givenNum));

        } catch(InputMismatchException e) {

            System.out.println("Looks like you entered a non integer value.");

        } finally {

            in.close();

        }
    }
}
```

`Convert` class:

```
public final class convert{

    private convert() {
        // removes the default constructor
    }

    public static String getBinary(int given) {
        char binNumbers[] = {'0','1'}; 
        String str = "";
        int rem;
            while (given > 0) {
                rem = given % 2;
                str = binNumbers[rem] + str;
                given /= 2;
            }
        return str;
    }

    public static String getOctal(int given) {
       char octalNumbers[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7'}; 
       String str = "";
       int rem;
           while (given > 0) {
               rem = given % 8;
               str = octalNumbers[rem] + str;
               given /= 8;
            } 
       return str;
    }

    public static String getHex(int given) {
        char hexNumbers[] = {'0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','A','B','C','D','E','F'};
        String str = "";
        int rem;
            while(given > 0){
                rem = given % 16;
                str = hexNumbers[rem] + str;
                given /= 16;
            }
        return str;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Did I missed something?
- Is there a more efficient implementation of this program?

Comment: Related: [`Integer.toString(int, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toString-int-int-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First: Please format your code more consistently.

The indention of the `while`loop is very unusual. Better (and more common):

```
public static String getBinary(int given) {
    char binNumbers[] = {'0','1'}; 
    String str = "";
    int rem;
    while (given > 0) {
        rem = given % 2;
        str = binNumbers[rem] + str;
        given /= 2;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Next: Please use the default cases for identifiers. Classes should start upper case (`Convert` instead of `convert`).

Also use `StringBuilder` instead of `String`-concatenation:

```
public static String getBinary(int given) {
    char binNumbers[] = {'0','1'}; 
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int rem;
    while (given > 0) {
        rem = given % 2;
        sb.append(binNumbers[rem]);
        given /= 2;
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Ths will be a large performace gain. Your code basically translates to:

```
public static String getBinary(int given) {
    char binNumbers[] = {'0','1'}; 
    String str = "";
    int rem;
    while (given > 0) {
        rem = given % 2;
        //str = binNumbers[rem] + str;
        // Code generated by compiler for the above line of code
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        sb.append(binNumbers[rem]);
        sb.append(str);
        str = sb.toString();
        // End of generated code
        given /= 2;
    }
    return str;
}
```

As you can see the code generated many objects which have to be cleaned up afterwards by the Garbage Collector.

*Hint:*

You can use `Integer.toString(given, 2)` instead of your `Convert.getBinary(given)` for the same result.

Answer (score 2):

I have already stated the obvious [in my comment](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/91039/binary-conversion-in-java#comment165102_91039), so I'll focus on the other parts of your code.

It's nice that you know how to use `try-with-resources`, but that also means you don't need the `finally` clause.

Your `convert` class should be `Converter` (note the title case), and your comment here is misleading:

```
private convert() {
    // removes the default constructor
}
```

Yes, it's understood that utility classes often do not have a `public` constructor, so you should either mention something to that extent, or just put a dummy comment (more to suppress empty code block warnings for the latter):

```
private Converter() {
    // utility class do not need public constructor
}
```

As for your actual conversion implementations, note that they tend to follow the pattern:

- declare a `char[]` array of valid outputs
- perform a modulus based on the *length* of the `char[]` array
- perform an integer division and loop till this yields `0`

As such, you can probably have the following `private static` method to standardize this:

```
private static String doConvert(int input, char[] values) {
    int base = values.length; // 2, 8, 16
    int rem;
    // ...
}

// illustration
public static String toBinary(int given) {
    // can consider putting new char[]{'0','1'} as a static field too
    return doConvert(given, new char[]{'0','1'});
}
```